# How to pass same value to two classes through intent in android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am passing the Position of `ListView` Item to Next `Class`. I need to pass this same position to Another `Class`. What should i do? 
Here what i am doing.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int index=position+1;
            Intent it=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("paya",index);
            startActivity(it);
```

//Now Here I declared another Intent. Is this Right thing?? Or is there another way to pass same thing to two classes??

```
            Intent it2=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
            it2.putExtra("paya",index);
            startActivity(it2);

        }
    });
```

Waiting :)

Comment: Are you trying to start two activities at the same time?

Comment: I didnt Understand.. What do you mean by at same time??

Comment: Actually I want to pass this position to two classes at a same time when this code run..

Comment: Are you calling `startActivity()` twice in `onItemClick()`?

Comment: Yes... Dats what i am doing... nd I know something is wrong

Comment: You can only have one activity running at a time... You should only call `startActivity()` once in your `onItemClick()`

Comment: Then What should i do??  MacLean

Comment: I mean i have to pass this Value to two classes..

Comment: There is no way for me to figure out what you should do given the context you provided. I don't know what either activity should do so it's up to you to either combine the activities or call `AnotherActivity` from inside `NextActivity`

Comment: Please only use the [android-studio] tag if you have a question about the tool itself, **not** for general programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a value to be persistent throughout your entire application you can use any of the methods [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to store a value and retrieve it later. The simplest one in my opinion is `SharedPreferences` so I would suggest using that.

Comment: Thanks MacLean. I think i have to go for SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

A class and an activity has different meanings for android. You can't have multiple activities running at the same time. So, if you want to call one activity and then call another, you need to pass the values with the second intent.

Comment: Then is it right to call startActivity() function twice in on click??